# Get record by ID using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How can I change the following action to get a single result by ID?
I have the following code to get All records from the database, I want to modifiy it so that I can get a single record.

```
namespace PDS.Core.App.Data.Action.Product
{
    public class GetProducts_Action : BaseEFAction<GetProducts_Action_Request, GetProducts_Action_Response>
    {
        private CRMSContext Context { get; }
        private IMapper Mapper { get; }

        public GetProducts_Action(ILogger<GetProducts_Action> logger, CRMSContext context, ITransactionManager scope, IMapper mapper) : base(logger, context, scope)
        {
            Context = context.ValidateAndConsumeNonNullableArgument(nameof(context));
            Mapper = mapper.ValidateAndConsumeNonNullableArgument(nameof(mapper));
        }

        protected override async Task<GetProducts_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(GetProducts_Action_Request request)
        {
            var tb_Products = await Context.TB_Products
                .ToListAsync();

            var tb_ProductsDTOs = Mapper.Map<IList<TB_ProductDTO>>(tb_Products);
            return new GetProducts_Action_Response { TB_Products = tb_ProductsDTOs };
        }
    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Request : BaseActionRequest
    {

    }

    public class GetProducts_Action_Response : BaseActionResponse
    {
        public IList<TB_ProductDTO> TB_Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can filter results using the `.Where()` Linq extension.

Comment: @MarkC. Thanks Marc, how can i compare ids?

Comment: Use an appropriate linq extension method (such as Where, Single, SingleOrDefault), for example `Context.TB_Products.Single(x => x.Id == yourIdParameter);`

Comment: ` protected override async Task<GetProducts_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(int id, GetProducts_Action_Request request)` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the code a bit if you extend the code instead of modifying it.

First, you can create a new request class similar to `GetProducts_Action_Request` that has `ProductId` in order to use it for getting a single product item. For example, let's say `GetProduct_Action_Request`:

```
public class GetProduct_Action_Request : BaseActionRequest
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
}
```

And response object that has single product:

```
public class GetProduct_Action_Response : BaseActionResponse
{
    public TB_ProductDTO TB_Product { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create new action `GetProduct_Action` similar to `GetProducts_Action`. And you can use [`SingleOrDefaultAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync) to return the only Product element that satisfies a `Id` condition:

```
public class GetProduct_Action : BaseEFAction<GetProduct_Action_Request, GetProduct_Action_Response>
{
    private CRMSContext Context { get; }
    private IMapper Mapper { get; }

    public GetProduct_Action(ILogger<GetProduct_Action> logger, CRMSContext context, ITransactionManager scope, IMapper mapper) : base(logger, context, scope)
    {
        Context = context.ValidateAndConsumeNonNullableArgument(nameof(context));
        Mapper = mapper.ValidateAndConsumeNonNullableArgument(nameof(mapper));
    }

    protected override async Task<GetProduct_Action_Response> PerformActionAsync(GetProduct_Action_Request request)
    {
        var tb_Product = await Context.TB_Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i=> i.Id == request.ProductId);

        var tb_ProductDTO = Mapper.Map<IList<TB_ProductDTO>>(tb_Product);
        return new GetProduct_Action_Response { TB_Product = tb_ProductDTO };
    }
}

public class GetProduct_Action_Request : BaseActionRequest
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
}

public class GetProduct_Action_Response : BaseActionResponse
{
    public TB_ProductDTO TB_Product { get; set; }
}
```

Therefore you have 2 actions `GetProduct_Action` for a single product based on `Id` and `GetProducts_Action` for a list of all products.